# row wise function in dplyr r

Tags: r, dplyr, rowwise

I am new to r and just trying the row wise function. But it seems did not really give me what I wanted.

```
df1 <- data.frame(Y1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
              Y2 = c(1, 3, 4, 2, 6),
              Y3 = c(4, 1, 0, 0, 1))

df0 = df1 %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Maximum = max(Y1:Y3)) %>% select(Y1:Y3,Maximum)
```

And the output given is as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9C0Jj.jpg)

which is just not right in terms of the maximum value over the rows.

Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: What is it that you wanted? Can you provide a desired output

Comment: `max(Y1, Y2, Y3)` works instead of `max(Y1:Y3)` and from the answer from marked duplicate if you use `pmax` you can eliminate `rowwise` altogether.

Comment: Oh yeah.. Thanks Ronak